# Defining a variable by appending two variable names together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I've been working on editing and creating various path variables for some automated test scripts so that as I change software versions of my application I'm testing, all I need to do in the code is to change a single variable called `version`.

The code looks like this:

```
//App path
var appPath = "Windows (C:)\\Program Files\\APP\\";

//App exe versions
var appV2_0 = "App v2.0\\"
var appV2_1 = "App v2.1\\"

//App current version
var version = appV2_1

export var AppVersion = appPath + version + "Bin\\";
```

I'm also working on making some functions that will automatically export various "outputs" from our tests to a shared drive where other team members can grab them as they want. I'm trying to handle the paths to these directories in a similar fashion. That looks like this so far:

```
////Share Drive variables
var ShareDrive = "\\\\shareDrive\\Path\\To\\Drive\\APP\\";

//Share Drive Major Versions
var appV2_0_SD = "AP SW\\v2.0\\";
var appV2_1_SD = "AP SW\\v2.1\\";

//Share Drive Minor Versions
//v2.0
var appV2_0a_SD = "v2.0a\\Test Files\\AutoTCs\\";
var appV2_0b_SD = "v2.0b\\Test Files\\AutoTCs\\";

//v2.1
var appV2_1a_SD = "v2.1a\\Test Files\\AutoTCs\\";
var appV2_1b_SD = "v2.1b\\Test Files\\AutoTCs\\";

//Test Files -- Version Directories
var appV2_0a_TestFiles = ShareDrive + appV2_0_SD + appV2_0a_SD;
var appV2_0b_TestFiles = ShareDrive + appV2_0_SD + appV2_0b_SD;
var appV2_1a_TestFiles = ShareDrive + appV2_1_SD + appV2_1a_SD;
var appV2_1b_TestFiles = ShareDrive + appV2_1_SD + appV2_1b_SD;

export var shareDriveTestFiles = [HERE IS THE CRUX OF MY QUESTION].....
```

Ultimately, it would be fairly easy to simply put whatever new version shows up in both the `version` variable and the `shareDriveTestFiles` variable. However, since I've used the same nomenclature for naming my variables, I was hoping that I might be able to define the `shareDriveTestFiles` variable using the `version` variable similar to how I can append a string using a variable (e.g. "Hello " + worldText + "!") so that maybe I could define it something like `shareDriveTestFiles = verson + _TestFiles` so that changing the version will also cause it to select the correct variable under the "Test Files -- Version Directories" comment.

Hopefully that long explanation was clear enough. I tried googling around but I wasn't even sure how to word what I was searching for. So please, let me know if I can clear anything up.

Comment: Just use a dictionary or an array.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Could you elaborate a little on that?

Comment: Don't try and make variables with dynamic names like that. Have a JavaScript object, and make the keys to it strings that you construct however you like.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, the answer you marked this as duplicate is not the same issue I'm describing. That is adding an iterative value onto a variable name. This is not simply adding a increasing numerical value to the end of a variable name.

Comment: It does not need to be an increasing number. Again, the idea is just to use map keys instead of plain variables. Those answers are quit in-depth.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay, I'm fairly new to JavaScript so that doesn't mean a lot to me. I'll try googling that and see what I can find.

Comment: Have you used maps/dictionaries/JavaScript objects before? Like `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes. I've used those to choose inputs from drop downs in a GUI.